# Display data from API in table

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hey guys i have a question relating reading of data from API and displaying it with the help of the modul *react-native-paper*.When trying to access the data i get just empy fields, This my current state so far:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, View} from "react-native";


export default function () {



    const [data, setData] = useState({})
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);


    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(
            "dummyData"
        )
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => setData(json.features))
            .catch((error) => console.error(error))
            .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    }, []);

    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
           <DataTable.Row>
      <DataTable.Cell>Frozen yogurt</DataTable.Cell>
      <DataTable.Cell numeric>159</DataTable.Cell>
      <DataTable.Cell numeric>6.0</DataTable.Cell>
    </DataTable.Row>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you are accessing is you wrong
you set json.features which is an array

So you should access the 'LAN_ew_GEN' property like below

```
data[0].attributes.LAN_ew_GEN
```

This will get the value of first element of LAN_ew_GEN you can also consider using a map.

Comment: Iam getting the following error : TypeError: data.features is undefined

Comment: Sorry you already assign the features array to data, updated the answer

Comment: Yeah i got it already anyway, thanks alot. Is there a better way to do this as i have multiple counties?

Comment: Better filter at API level if possible, or if there is a way to get the metadata at api level you should use that

Comment: Iam still getting undefined error, i probably why iam getting the error as i use the same API in two seperate classes. can i link it to you in chat?

Comment: sure, the response from your url has the structure features which is an array of objects with structure attributes and geometry

Comment: could you invite to me a steckoverflow chat room? as i dont have the privileges yet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217323/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-voltage).